# Google bucket file uploading not working in production environment

Tags: node.js, file-upload, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

My platform has an issue uploading to google cloud storage that I'm only experiencing in the production environment and that is real head-scratcher. My platform uses NodeJS and this file upload is being done on the backend in an API service.

Language: Javascript, `nodejs version 6.5`

Packages used: `@google-cloud/storage version 0.2.0`, `gm version 1.23.0`

The service essentially takes the image in base 64, creates a buffer of the image, then pipes that image to the google cloud bucket. Easy peasy.

Unfortunately its not working on production, and I cannot figure out why. The exact same code runs in production, it just points to a different bucket.

**Some relevant code at the top of the file**

```
var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var Q = require('q');
var request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });
var gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({
      keyFilename: sails.config.gcloud.keyFileName,
      projectId: sails.config.gcloud.projectId
});
var bucket = gcs.bucket(sails.config.gcloud.buckets.cdn);

// Takes raw base64Image from client and converts it into:
// {
//      meta: data:image/jpeg;base64,
//      data: hugeStringOfImageDataInBase64,
//      dateType: image/jpeg
// }
function decodeImage(base64Image) {
    // Not using regex due to perf.
    var startImageData = base64Image.indexOf(',');
    var regex = /^data:(.+);base64$/;
    var meta = base64Image.slice(0, startImageData);
    var data = base64Image.slice(startImageData + 1);
    var dataType = meta.match(regex)[1];

    return { type: dataType, meta: meta, data: data };
}
```

**Relevant code where buffer is being created**

```
createNewPictureAndUploadToCDNBase: function(imageInBase64, imageBuffer, cb) {

    return Picture.create()
        .then(function(emptyPicture) {
            var buffer;

            if (imageInBase64) {
                buffer = PictureService.bufferFromBase64(imageInBase64);
            } else {
                buffer = imageBuffer;
            }

            return PictureService.resizeAndUploadPictureToCDN(emptyPicture.id, buffer, function (err, results) {

                emptyPicture = _.merge(emptyPicture, results);

                return emptyPicture.save(function(err) {
                    cb(err, emptyPicture);
                });
            });

        }).catch(function(err) {
            return cb(err);
        });
},

bufferFromBase64: function (imageInBase64) {
    return new Buffer(decodeImage(imageInBase64).data, 'base64');
},
```

**Main part of the code where file's being piped to Google Cloud Storage bucket**

```
resizeAndUploadPictureToCDN: function (pictureId, imageBuffer, cb) {

    var resizingOptions = {
        original: {
            quality: 80,
            size: {}
        },
        thumbnail: {
            quality: 75,
            size: {
                width: 60,
                height: 60
            }
        },
        medium: {
            quality: 65,
            size: {height: 250}
        }
    };

    var resizingPromises = _.mapValues(resizingOptions, function (options, resizingName) {

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var file = bucket.file(pictureId + '-' + resizingName);

            // NOTE: 'gm' is a call to GraphicMagick for node
            // More can be found here: https://github.com/aheckmann/gm

            gm(imageBuffer)
                .quality(options.quality)
                .resize(options.size.width || null, options.size.height || null)
                .stream()
                .pipe(file.createWriteStream())
                .on('finish', function(err, success) {

                    file.getMetadata(function(err, metadata) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("Error getting metadata from google cloud", err);
                            return reject(err);
                        }

                        resolve(metadata.mediaLink);
                    });

                }).on('error', function(err) {
                    console.log("Got an error uploading to Cloud Storage:", err);
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
    });

    Promise.props(resizingPromises)
        .then(function (results) {
            cb(null, results);
        }).error(cb);
},
```

Don't worry much about that resizing language, I'm confident that part's not the issue. Just takes the images and uploads a few different versions with different sizes. I'm much more confident that will work the same locally as on production than the filestream and interacting with Google Cloud Storage.

So yeah. When I run that locally, uploading to one bucket, it works great. When its run in production, using a different bucket, it fails to upload the image.

However, in both cases I do not get an error message. Instead when it fails, I still get that the file was uploaded successfully. Just when I visit the location of that file, on production it's completely empty of any data.

**Read out from production environment of that console.log under `file.getMetaData()`**

```
Corresponding metadata:  
{
    kind: 'storage#object',
    id: 'cdn.texasca.com/5a3d938b84d560010012b0b3-thumbnail/1513984907989412',
    selfLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/cdn.texasca.com/o/5a3d938b84d560010012b0b3-thumbnail',
    name: '5a3d938b84d560010012b0b3-thumbnail',
    bucket: 'cdn.texasca.com',
    generation: '1513984907989412',
    metageneration: '1',
    timeCreated: '2017-12-22T23:21:47.915Z',
    updated: '2017-12-22T23:21:47.915Z',
    storageClass: 'STANDARD',
    timeStorageClassUpdated: '2017-12-22T23:21:47.915Z',
    size: '0',
    md5Hash: '1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==',
    mediaLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/cdn.texasca.com/o/5a3d938b84d560010012b0b3-thumbnail?generation=1513984907989412&alt=media',
    crc32c: 'AAAAAA==',
    etag: 'CKSji6XhntgCEAE=' 
}
```

Notice how it says `size '0'`  as in the file size is 0. Everything else looks **exactly** the same as it does after streaming a file to the other google bucket from the local environment, except for it has a file size like '13908' or some such and when you visit the `mediaLink` location it has a full-size image, not just nothing.

I'm really having trouble debugging...

Where should I start with debugging such an issue? Are there commonly used ways of debugging a filestream? Does anyone know why I'm not getting an error message from this filestream?

Really trying to avoid a full rewrite of this part of my platform.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

**THINGS I'VE TRIED SINCE INITIALLY POSTING QUESTION**

So to fix this issue, I've tried a few things so far. The first one was creating new keys for the service account. So I did that, linked that key in my code and tried it. Same issue, works in local development mode, doesn't work in production (get that weird non-error where it doesn't throw an error but the object size is **0**).

Also, as I mentioned there's two buckets. One is named `dev0.cdn.texasca.com` and the other is named `cdn.texasca.com`. In local development mode I switched it to uploading images to `cdn.texasca.com` instead of the dev one and... BOOM! Still same issue. Works great when I run the platform locally but fails in production.

I also tried giving my service account more "roles" thinking that might solve the issue. Has made no difference.

That's all I've tried so far. Feeling really blocked on this issue so I'm moving on to some other things for a day or two so I can get some productive features and bug fixes out. Hoping for some more suggestions!

Comment: imagemagick is definitely installed on your production machine, right? since a file is getting created in your bucket, it shouldn't be a permissions issue. Can you check that gm is working correctly?

Comment: That's a very interesting observation. @njLT will inspect over lunch and report back

Comment: Hey, its definitely installed. I was able to check that at least. Whether its working "properly" or not is much harder to test. I'm not completely sure its "working properly"... could possibly be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem **was** something going wrong with GraphicMagick in the production environment. Still haven't figured out exactly what that was, but the solution was to rewrite the file uploading without GraphicMagick.

I rewrote the code without GraphicMagick for now.

```
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var file = bucket.file(pictureId + '-' + resizingName);

            var stream = file.createWriteStream();

            stream.on('error', function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Got an error uploading to GBucket: ", err);
                    return reject(err);
                }
            });

            stream.on('finish', function() {

                console.log("Uploaded successfully!!");

                file.getMetadata(function(err, metadata) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error getting metadata from google cloud", err);
                        return reject(err);
                    }

                    console.log("File's metadata: ", metadata);

                    return resolve(metadata.mediaLink);
                });     
            });

            stream.end(imageBuffer);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

If the code is working on one bucket but failing on another, the thing to check is the service account you're running your code under, and if that service account has permissions to write to the target production bucket that is currently failing.

Here is a link that gives info about authentication and scopes into storage:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication

and also, here is a link about service accounts:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: OK, trying to follow this vein of fixing it today! Thanks <3

Comment: Just for the record, this did not help unfortunately. Auto-selected your answer for the bounty because it ran out.